# Cosa significa "infrociarsi"?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs, regional

Nel romanzo *Il fu Mattia Pascal* di Luigi Pirandello ho letto:

> Appena arrivato, si toglieva dal taschino del panciotto un vecchio cipollone di rame, e lo appendeva a muro con tutta la formidabile catena; sedeva, coi due bastoni fra le gambe, traeva di tasca la papalina, la tabacchiera e un pezzolone a dadi rossi e neri; **s'infrociava** una grossa presa di tabacco, si puliva, poi apriva il cassetto del tavolino e ne traeva un libraccio che apparteneva alla biblioteca: *Dizionario storico dei musicisti, artisti e amatori morti e viventi*, stampato a Venezia nel 1758.

La mia domanda è sul significato del verbo "infrociarsi" in questo brano. L'ho cercato in parecchi dizionari, ma non l'ho trovato. Sapreste dirmi cosa vuol dire?

Comment: Nel linguaggio informale corrente ha naturalmente ben altra connotazzione.

Comment: https://www.dizionario-italiano.it/dizionario-italiano.php?lemma=INFROCIARE100

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Deve sicuramente avere a che fare con le [frogie](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/frogia/), cioè le narici del cavallo e, per estensione, quelle dell'uomo. Quel personaggio, cioè, si infila nelle narici la presa di tabacco, con il possibile connotato ulteriore che le narici saranno ampie e abituate a questo atto.

Quanto alla “c” al posto della “g” (ma nemmeno “infrogiarsi” è registrato nei dizionari che ho consultato), posso ipotizzare un refuso o un influsso regionale. In romanesco, per esempio, *infrocia'* esiste, con il senso di

> Introdursi in un passaggio angusto; imbattersi, scontrarsi con una persona; urtare con violenza contro un ostacolo. Dal costringere con la forza, domare, un animale, in particolare un cavallo, prendendolo per le froge (v. “frocia”).

(F. Ravaro, *Dizionario romanesco*, Newton Compton)

Il significato è quindi tutt'altro (anche se un passaggio angusto c'entra in ogni caso), ma è confermato il nesso con le frogie del cavallo.

Answer (score 2):

Soltanto per aggiungere una fonte alla risposta di @DaG, il significato di "infrociare" dal [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI07/00001004.jpg) che è adatto al contesto del brano citato nella domanda è il seguente:

> **Infrociare,** tr. (*infròcio*). Dial. Cacciare su per
> le narici; annusare tabacco. 
>       *Pirandello*, 8-110: Terminata la preghiera, il prete, dagli occhi impassibili, s’infrociò una grossa presa di tabacco.