# Cos'è un "pezzolone a dadi rossi e neri"?

Tags: meaning

Questa domanda fa riferimento allo stesso brano del romanzo *Il fu Mattia Pascal*, di Luigi Pirandello, che ho riportato in [questo altro post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/8023/707):

> Appena arrivato, si toglieva dal taschino del panciotto un vecchio cipollone di rame, e lo appendeva a muro con tutta la formidabile catena; sedeva, coi due bastoni fra le gambe, traeva di tasca la papalina, la tabacchiera e **un pezzolone a dadi rossi e neri**; s'infrociava una grossa presa di tabacco, si puliva, poi apriva il cassetto del tavolino e ne traeva un libraccio che apparteneva alla biblioteca: *Dizionario storico dei musicisti, artisti e amatori morti e viventi*, stampato a Venezia nel 1758.

Non sono sicura di aver capito cos'è "un pezzolone a dadi rossi e neri". Ho pensato fosse un fazzoletto a quadretti rossi e neri, ma non sono riuscita ad ottenere nessuna conferma a questa ipotesi. Non ho trovato il vocabolo "pezzolone" in nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato e neanche alla voce "pezzo" ho visto nulla a riguardo. Tuttavia, sul [dizionario di Sinonimi e Contrari Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fazzoletto_(Sinonimi-e-Contrari)/) ho appreso che "pezzola" è un sinonimo regionale di "fazzoletto". Quindi, sapreste spiegarmi qual è il significato di "pezzolone a dadi rossi e neri"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La tua supposizione è corretta: si sta sicuramente parlando di un grosso fazzoletto; il termine "pezzolone" deriva da "pezzola" ed è un accrescitivo (http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/A/accrescitivo.shtml)
utilizzato nel testo in modo ironico.

Comment: C'è bisogno di un link ad “accrescitivo”? :-O Perché non anche a “supposizione” o “ironico”?

Comment: @DaG serve solo per indicare alcuni esempi di utilizzo. Ciao.